# Cython UserWarning: Unknown Extension options: 'cython_compile_time_env'

Tags: python, cython

Using cython version 0.11.2, would like to conditionally compile some parts of code on .pyx file.
below is the code in setup.py

```
CythonExtension('sslip2', sources = ['sslip2.pyx'],
        cython_compile_time_env=dict(CONCOM=1),
        libraries = ['ssl'],
        ),
```

in sslip2.pyx file

```
IF CONCOM== 1:
    def something():
```

but this is returning below warning and not helpful,

```
UserWarning: Unknown Extension options: 'cython_compile_time_env'
```

is it possible to define some variable in Cython Extension and use the same in .pyx file for conditional compilation, I am new to Cython and i think something is missing here, really appreciate any pointers on conditionally compiling the code

Comment: Is there a good reason to be using a Cython version released in 2009?

Comment: yes, i'm using it virtual environment and have other dependencies, unable to upgrade

Comment: As far as I can see `cython_compile_time_env` doesn't appear in the [2009 code](https://github.com/cython/cython/blob/df9b64317d9fadc2bdb0c23f23e31bc54781136b/Cython/Distutils/extension.py) so it may just be a feature that was added later

Comment: You may be right, i couldn't confirm though, i am looking for any feature through which we can achieve conditional compilation in .pyx file

Comment: This may not work because it's hard to know reliably what's available in these older versions, but here's the hack I'd try. Do `include settings.pxi` in your main file. In your setup script write some code that writes `settings.pxi` with appropriate `DEF` statements.